# Can fat make rubber gloves stiff?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, rubber

Sometimes I use dishwashing gloves when carving cooked duck, which is very fatty. I have noticed that over time my dishwashing gloves seem to be shrinking a little bit and getting stiff. Could this be because of the fat?

Comment: Maybe, if it was "washing off" plasticiser from surface.

Comment: Fat could diffuse into the glove rubber and let it swell a bit. That would make the material become stiffer, and because it is originally stretched, shrink a bit in the direction it was stretched.

Comment: Plasticiser in gloves? Come on!

Comment: @Karl PVC glove (have seen thin one time use ones) need plasticisers, because pure PVC is just hard and brittle.

Comment: For a good answer, we need to know the material of the gloves - just roughly is enough, but details help, of course. The product name may be helpful.